# jQueryPlugin: return this vs return this.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Yes, there are many topics about that, but I still didn't get it.

I prepared two jsfiddle:

[return this](http://jsfiddle.net/gGPbH/2/)

[return this.each()](http://jsfiddle.net/LCRtd/2/)

What's the difference?
There any many answers, but my examples show the same output. So some some of these answers might be wrong!?

---

> [what does "return this.each()" do in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351620/what-does-return-this-each-do-in-jquery)

"It allows for one to call a plugin or an event on a bunch of elements and then apply that same function or event to all of them" --> work's with `return this` as well

"It allows you to chain multiple functions" --> same here

"Allows you to do things like: `$("mySelector").foo().show();`" --> I still can do this as well, when I use `return this`

---

I also created another jsfiddle that shows - in my opinion - that it doesn't matter if you're wrapping you code into `return this.each();`:

http://jsfiddle.net/7S3MW/1/

The Chrome Console shows the same output!

So what's the difference?

Comment: case is to simple, what if you wanted a node specific filter... try logging `$(this).text()` within the one without `each`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your examples are flawed in that they do exactly the same thing to each element.
2. The real issue isn't `return this` versus `return this.each`, the issue is `this` versus `this.each`.

For **(1)**, consider the difference between this plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        this.append(' - ' + this.data('x'));
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eyHeu/

And this plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).append(' - ' + $(this).data('x'));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5dMMH/

So you see, you need to use `this.each` if you need to treat the individual elements in the `this` set differently. You would have similar effects if your plugin had to attach element-specific data to each element: if you didn't use `each` then you'd end up attaching the exact same piece of data to all of the elements inside `this` and that would just leave you confused about why information is bleeding all over the place.

For **(2)**, it doesn't matter if you `return this` or `return this.each(...` since [`x.each(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) returns `x` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you two "equivalent" pieces of code that could clarify your question:

**With jQuery "each" function:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).append(' - ' + $(this).data('x'));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Without jQuery "each" function:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mangle = function(options) {
        var objs = this;
        for (var i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
            var obj = objs[i];
            $(obj).append(' - ' + $(obj).data('x'));
        };
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So, basically, `each` function is used to apply some code to all elements contained in `this` object (*as `this` usually refers to a group of elements returned by a jQuery selector*) and return the reference to `this` (*as `each` function always returns that reference -to allow chaining calls-*)

**As a side note**:  The second approach (*-`for` loop-*) is faster (notably on old browsers) than former one (*-`each` function-*).

Answer (score 0):

They are both exactly the same. `.each()` returns `this`, so `return this.each()` is EXACTLY the same as `this.each();` `return this;`

Edit: your newest fiddle's `makeRed` method doesn't return `this` and is therefore not chainable.

Comment: yop, changed it, the 3rd fiddle was just to check if it's equal, so there are about on thousand tutorial in the internet, telling wrong stuff??

Comment: Sort of. The return values will be the same but the overall behavior can be radically different depending on what the plugin does.